# Replacing strings with inline html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few keywords within a paragraph of text that need to be replaced by inline html dynamically. What would be the best way to go about this, using jQuery?

e.g.:

```
<p> 
Lorem :XXXX: dolor sit amet,  
consetetur :YYYY: elitr.
</p>
```

should end up like:

```
<p> 
Lorem <span class="XXXX"></span> dolor sit amet, 
consetetur <span class="YYYY"></span> elitr.
</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery for this, but I'm guessing you are already using it elsewhere on the page. Assuming the text inside the `p` tag is just regular text and you aren't trying to parse arbitrary HTML, you could do something like this

```
var item = $('p');
var htmltext = item.text();
htmltext = htmltext.replace(/:(\w+):/g, '<span class="$1"></span>');
item.html(htmltext);
```

This is also assuming "p" is the selector you want. Also assuming the pattern isn't always ":XXXX:" You may have to adjust the RegEx depending on what your desired goal is.

Comment: var $p = $('p');
var htmltext = $p.text();

Comment: Good point; that will reduce the likelihood that HTML will get in there for the RegEx comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to load framework for this, simple pure JS solution:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var replacements = [':XXXX:', ':YYYY:'];

for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(replacements[i], '<span>' + replacements[i] + '</span>');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ung9610/1/

OR using regex:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(:\w+:)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ung9610/3/